# Dealing with NuGet content folder created on Octopus

Tags: nuget, octopus-deploy

So when I create a NuGet package and put my website files into the /content folder (within the NuGet package) it results in a /content folder being created when Octopus extracts the NuGet package on the destination server.

What's the best way of just extracting the folders and files within the /content folder without having a /content folder created?

Cheers,

-- Lee

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can just remove the target="content" and the file(s) will just be put in the root. Exactly what I wanted.

So instead of

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\Release\**\*.*" target="content" /> 
</files>
```

the following should work..

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\Release\**\*.*" /> 
</files>
```

-- Lee